# Rails rspec test returning is returning an empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I want to filter a list of movies by format. This works correctly on my view - shows only movies in the DVD format. Puts statements also show the correct response in the terminal. My rspec test should find the first movie by ID but fails as it returns an empty array.

Controller code:

```
movie_response = #APICALL returns JSON array of movies
dvd_format = []

movie_response.each do |found_movies|

 if found_movies.format == "DVD"
  dvd_format << found_movies
 end
 movie_response = @application.movies
end

@application.movies = movie_response
```

However, I know the Rspec test works as it finds the first movie by ID when I am not using the DVD filter with the code below.

Controller code:

```
movie_response = #APICALL returns JSON array of movies

@application.movies = movie_response
```

Could anyone push me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: what's in `APICALL`? I'm guessing you are stubbing it (you souldn't do real api calls during tests)

Comment: Sorry yes, the API call gets a JSON array of movie data

Comment: but what's actually in it on your test? what did you put inside to stub it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll get into too much trouble if you try to consume an external API in your tests.

I usually use https://github.com/bblimke/webmock to mock external calls.